# Writing a pandas DataFrame to CSV file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas which I would like to write to a CSV file.

I am doing this using:

```py
df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

And getting the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u03b1' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)
```

- Is there any way to get around this easily (i.e. I have unicode characters in my data frame)?
- And is there a way to write to a tab delimited file instead of a CSV using e.g. a 'to-tab' method (that I don't think exists)?

Answer (score 1482, accepted):

To delimit by a tab you can use the `sep` argument of [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t')
```

To use a specific encoding (e.g. 'utf-8') use the `encoding` argument:

```
df.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: I would add `index=False` to drop the index.

Answer (score 395):

When you are storing a `DataFrame` object into a **csv file** using the `to_csv` method, you probably wont be needing to store the **preceding indices** of each **row** of the `DataFrame` object.

You can **avoid** that by passing a `False` boolean value to `index` parameter.

Somewhat like:

```
df.to_csv(file_name, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

So if your DataFrame object is something like:

```
  Color  Number
0   red     22
1  blue     10
```

The csv file will store:

```
Color,Number
red,22
blue,10
```

instead of (the case when the **default value** `True` was passed)

```
,Color,Number
0,red,22
1,blue,10
```

Answer (score 63):

To write a pandas DataFrame to a CSV file, you will need [**`DataFrame.to_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv). This function offers many arguments with reasonable defaults that you will more often than not need to override to suit your specific use case. For example, you might want to use a different separator, change the datetime format, or drop the index when writing. `to_csv` has arguments you can pass to address these requirements.

Here's a table listing some common scenarios of writing to CSV files and the corresponding arguments you can use for them.

[image: Write to CSV ma dude]

> **Footnotes**
>
> 1. The default separator is assumed to be a comma (`','`). Don't change this unless you know you need to.
> 2. By default, the index of `df` is written as the first column. If your DataFrame does not have an index (IOW, the `df.index` is the default `RangeIndex`), then you will want to set `index=False` when writing. To explain this in a different way, if your data DOES have an index, you can (and should) use `index=True` or just leave it out completely (as the default is `True`).
> 3. It would be wise to set this parameter if you are writing string data so that other applications know how to read your data. This will also avoid any potential `UnicodeEncodeError`s you might encounter while saving.
> 4. Compression is recommended if you are writing large DataFrames (>100K rows) to disk as it will result in much smaller output files.
>    OTOH, it will mean the write time will increase (and consequently, the
>    read time since the file will need to be decompressed).

Answer (score 40):

Example of export in file with **full path on Windows** and in case your file has **headers**:

```
df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\John\Desktop\export_dataframe.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

For example, if you want to store the file in same directory where your script is, with **utf-8 encoding** and **tab as separator**:

```
df.to_csv(r'./export/dftocsv.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', header='true')
```

Answer (score 26):

Something else you can try if you are having issues encoding to 'utf-8' and want to go cell by cell you could try the following.

**Python 2**

(Where "df" is your DataFrame object.)

```
for column in df.columns:
    for idx in df[column].index:
        x = df.get_value(idx,column)
        try:
            x = unicode(x.encode('utf-8','ignore'),errors ='ignore') if type(x) == unicode else unicode(str(x),errors='ignore')
            df.set_value(idx,column,x)
        except Exception:
            print 'encoding error: {0} {1}'.format(idx,column)
            df.set_value(idx,column,'')
            continue
```

Then try:

```
df.to_csv(file_name)
```

---

You can check the encoding of the columns by:

```
for column in df.columns:
    print '{0} {1}'.format(str(type(df[column][0])),str(column))
```

Warning: errors='ignore' will just omit the character e.g.

```
IN: unicode('Regenexx\xae',errors='ignore')
OUT: u'Regenexx'
```

**Python 3**

```
for column in df.columns:
    for idx in df[column].index:
        x = df.get_value(idx,column)
        try:
            x = x if type(x) == str else str(x).encode('utf-8','ignore').decode('utf-8','ignore')
            df.set_value(idx,column,x)
        except Exception:
            print('encoding error: {0} {1}'.format(idx,column))
            df.set_value(idx,column,'')
            continue
```

Answer (score 21):

If above solution not working for anyone or the CSV is getting messed up, just remove `sep='\t'` from the line like this:

```
df.to_csv(file_name, encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 18):

Sometimes you face these problems if you specify UTF-8 encoding also.
I recommend you to specify encoding while reading file and same encoding while writing to file.
This might solve your problem.

Answer (score 12):

it could be not the answer for this case, but as I had the same error-message with `.to_csv`I tried `.toCSV('name.csv')` and the error-message was different ("`SparseDataFrame' object has no attribute 'toCSV'`). So the problem was solved by turning dataframe to dense dataframe

```
df.to_dense().to_csv("submission.csv", index = False, sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: You got the error in the second one as it looks like you used `.toCSV` and not `.to_csv`. You forgot the underscore

Answer (score 4):

I would avoid using the `'\t'` separate and would create issues when reading the dataset again.

`df.to_csv(file_name, encoding='utf-8')`

Answer (score 2):

##### 1. `errors=` is sometimes useful

If a file has to have a certain encoding but the existing dataframe has characters that cannot be represented, `errors=` can be used to "coerce" the data to be saved anyway at the *cost of losing information*. All possible values that can be passed as the `errors=` argument to the [`open()` function in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) can be passed here.

For example, the below code saves a csv with ascii encoding where the Japanese characters are replaced with a `?`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Shohei Ohtani は一生に一度の選手だ。']})
df.to_csv('data1.csv', encoding='ascii', errors='replace', index=False)

print(pd.read_csv('data1.csv'))

                           A
0  Shohei Ohtani ???????????
```

##### 2. `float_format=` is sometimes useful

You can format float dtypes using `float_format=` and doing so saves a lot of memory sometimes at *the cost of losing precision*. For example,

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [*range(1,9,3)]*1000})/3
df.to_csv('data1.csv', index=False)                       # 61,440 bytes on disk
df.to_csv('data2.csv', index=False, float_format='%.2f')  # 20,480 bytes on disk
```

##### 3. Save a compressed csv

Since pandas 1.0.0, you can pass a dict to compression that specifies compression method and file name inside the archive. The below code creates a zip file named `compressed_data.zip` which has a single file in it named `data.csv`.

```py
df.to_csv('compressed_data.zip', index=False, compression={'method': 'zip', 'archive_name': 'data.csv'})
# read the archived file as a csv
pd.read_csv('compressed_data.zip')
```

You can even add to an existing archive; simply pass `mode='a'`.

```py
df.to_csv('compressed_data.zip', compression={'method': 'zip', 'archive_name': 'data_new.csv'}, mode='a')
```