# Solving error "delimiter must be a 1-character string" while writing a dataframe to a csv file

Tags: pandas, delimiter

Using this question: [Pandas writing dataframe to CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923281/pandas-writing-dataframe-to-csv-file) as a model, I wrote the following code to make a csv file:

```
df.to_csv('/Users/Lab/Desktop/filteredwithheading.txt', sep='\s+', header=True)
```

But it returns the following error:

```
TypeError: "delimiter" must be an 1-character string
```

I have looked up the documentation for this here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html but I can't figure out what I am missing, or what that error means. I also tried using (sep='\s') in the code, but got the same error.

Comment: the code creates the file, but then does not write data in it.

Comment: If you would like the `sep` to be a space use `sep=' '`.

Comment: Just to expand on bernie's comment, `\s+` is a regex that matches 1 or more spaces. It's useful for *reading* csv's that use a variable number of spaces as a separator. You want to *write* your csv with single spaces separating.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the issue discussion ([here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6035)), this is not considered as a pandas issue but rather a compatibility issue of `python's csv module` with python2.x.

The workaround to solve it is to enclose the separator with `str(..)`. For example, here is how you can reproduce the problem, and then solve it:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'A'], ['b', 'B']])
df.to_csv(sep=',')
```

This will raise the following error:

```
TypeError ....              
----> 1 df.to_csv(sep=',')
TypeError: "delimiter" must be an 1-character string
```

The following however, will show the expected result

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'A'], ['b', 'B']])
df.to_csv(sep=str(','))
```

Output:

```
',0,1\n0,a,A\n1,b,B\n'
```

In your case, you should edit your code as follows:

```
df.to_csv('/Users/Lab/Desktop/filteredwithheading.txt', sep=str('\s+'), header=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that the although the solution to this error was using a string charcter instead of regex, pandas also raises this error when using `from __future__ import unicode_literals` with valid unicode characters. As of 2015-11-16, release 0.16.2, this error is still a known bug in pandas:
["to_csv chokes if not passed sep as a string, even when encoding is set to unicode" #6035](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005059/writing-a-pandas-to-a-csv-file)

For example, where df is a pandas DataFrame:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import pandas as pd

df.to_csv(pdb_seq_fp, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

> TypeError: "delimiter" must be an 1-character string

Using a [byte lteral](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=integer%20literal#integer-literals) with the specified encoding (default utf-8 with Python 3) `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` will resolve this in pandas 0.16.2: (`b'\t'`) —I haven't tested with previous versions or 0.17.0.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import pandas as pd

df.to_csv(pdb_seq_fp, sep=b'\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

(Note that with versions 0.13.0 - ???, it was necessary to use `pandas.compat import u`; but by 0.16.2 the byte literal is the way to go.)