# pandas to_csv - can't save a named csv into a specific path

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

Trying the simple task of converting a df to a csv, then saving it locally to a specific path. I'll censor the file name with "..." because I'm not sure about the privacy policy.

I checked many topics and I still run into errors, so I'll detail all the steps I went through, with the output:

Attempt #1:

```
import pandas as pd

file_name = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../titanic.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)

path = r'D:\PROJECTS\DATA_SCIENCE\UDEMY_DataAnalysisBootcamp'
df.to_csv(path, 'myDataFrame.csv')
```

> TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string

Attempt #2: After searching about "delimiter" issues, I discovered it was linked to the sep argument, so I used a solution from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005059/solving-error-delimiter-must-be-a-1-character-string-while-writing-a-dataframe) to set a proper separator and encoding.

```
import pandas as pd

file_name = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../titanic.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)

path = r'D:\PROJECTS\DATA_SCIENCE\UDEMY_DataAnalysisBootcamp'
df.to_csv(path, "myDataFrame.csv", sep=b'\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

> TypeError: to_csv() got multiple values for argument 'sep'

After playing with different arguments, it seems like my code use 'myDataFrame.csv' as the sep argument because when I remove it the code does not return error, but no file is create at the specified path, or anywhere (I checked the desktop, my documents, default "downloads" file).

I checked the documentation [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) and I didn't find a parameter that would allow me to set a specific name to the csv I want to locally create. I've been running in circles trying things that lead me to the same errors, without finding a way to save anything locally.

Even the simple code below does not create any csv, and I really don't understand why:

```
import pandas as pd

file_name = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../titanic.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)

df.to_csv("myDataFrame.csv")
```

I just want to simply save a dataframe into a csv, give it a name, and specify the path to where this csv is saved on my hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive the error because you are delivering to many values. The path and the file name must be provided in one string:

```
path = r'D:\PROJECTS\DATA_SCIENCE\UDEMY_DataAnalysisBootcamp'

df.to_csv(path +'/myDataFrame.csv')
```

This saves your file at the path you like.
However, the file of your last attempt should be saved at the root of your PYTHONPATH. Make sure to check on that. The file must exist.

Comment: Apologies for the dumb question, but could you elaborate on what you mean about "PYTHONPATH"?
I'm using google colab, and there is nothing on my google drive, nor on my hard drive. Or I did not find it. What would be the default path of that PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Normally if you run a python file, files you write will be stored in the working directory if you do not provide a specific path. To see what your working directory do `import os` and `os.getcwd()`

Comment: Output: '/content'.
I did not find this folder and have no idea where this should be... I'll set a new working directory.

Comment: Or you just provide the path you want. For example your drive

Comment: This could be interesting for you https://neptune.ai/blog/google-colab-dealing-with-files

Answer (score 1):

There is no seperate argument to give filename.
Provide name of the file in the path.

Change the code to this

```
path = r'D:\PROJECTS\DATA_SCIENCE\UDEMY_DataAnalysisBootcamp\myDataFrame.csv'
df.to_csv(path)
```