# Loop through multiple csv files, copying only certain columns to new files

Tags: python, bash, csv

I have a number of .csv files in a folder (1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv, etc.) and I need to loop over them all. The output should be a corresponding NEW file for each existing one, but each should only contain 2 columns.

Here is a sample of the csv files:

```
004,444.444.444.444,448,11:16 PDT,11-24-15
004,444.444.444.444,107,09:55 PDT,11-25-15
004,444.444.444.444,235,09:45 PDT,11-26-15
004,444.444.444.444,241,11:00 PDT,11-27-15
```

And here is how I would like the output to look:

```
448,11-24-15
107,11-25-15
235,11-26-15
241,11-27-15
```

Here is my working attempt at achieving this with Python:

```
import csv
import os
import glob

path = '/csvs/'
for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*csv') ):


    inputfile = open(infile, 'r') 
    output = os.rename(inputfile + ".out", 'w')

#Extracts the important columns from the .csv into a new file
with open(infile, 'r') as source:
    readr = csv.reader(source)
    with open(output,"w") as result:
        writr = csv.writer(result)
        for r in readr:
            writr.writerow((r[4], r[2]))
```

Using only the second half of this code, I am able to get the desired output by specifying the input files in the code. However, this Python script will be a small part of a much larger bash script that will be (hopefully) fully automated.

**How can I adjust the input of this script to loop over each file and create a new one with just the 2 specified columns?**

Please let me know if there is anything I need to clarify.

Comment: This file is sitting in the same folder as the files I am looping through.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inputfile` file is a file you openned , but then you are doing -

```
os.rename(inputfile + ".out", 'w')
```

This does not work, you are trying to add a string and the openned file using `+` operator. I am not even sure why you need that line or even the line - `inputfile = open(infile, 'r')` . You are openning the file again in the `with` statement.

Another issue -

1. You specify your path as - `path = '/csvs/'` , it is highly unlikely that you have a `'csvs'` directory under root directory. You may have wanted to use some other relative directory, so you should use relative directory.

You can just do -

```
path = 'csvs/'
for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*csv') ):
    output = infile + '.out'
    with open(infile, 'r') as source:
        readr = csv.reader(source)
        with open(output,"w") as result:
            writr = csv.writer(result)
            for r in readr:
                writr.writerow((r[4], r[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas library. It offers several functionality for dealing with csv files. [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) will read the csv file for you and give you a dataframe object. [Visit this link to get example about how to write csv file from pandas dataframe.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923281/pandas-writing-dataframe-to-csv-file) Moreore there are lot of tutorials available on the net.