# Extracting data using pandas from a CSV file with a special condition

Tags: csv, pandas, filtering

This is example of the data I have

```
1, "dep, anxiety", 30 
2, "dep"         , 40
4, "stress"      , 30
7, "dep, fobia"  , 20
```

I want to use pandas to filter rows having "dep" and save it in a new cvs file. output should be:

```
1, "dep, anxiety", 30
7, "dep, fobia"  , 20
2, "dep"         , 40
```

this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
patients =  pd.read_csv("patients.csv", encoding='latin-1')

print(patients["dep" in patients["qual"]])
```

that has the following error

```
"return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))"
```

And I do not know how to export the extracted data to new csv file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas writing dataframe to CSV file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923281/pandas-writing-dataframe-to-csv-file)

Comment: try this: `patients[patients.qual.str.contains('dep')].to_csv('c:/temp/dep.csv', index=False)`

Comment: Not a duplicate. The OP wants to know how to extract the rows containing `'dep'` before writing to CSV.

Comment: @MaxU, that's an answer ;). I think newer Pandas versions also support passing `lambda`s like this: `df[lambda row: "dep" in row["qual"]]`, can't try this out currently, though.

Comment: @filmor, yes, newer pandas versions do support indexing by callable, but i think `patients.qual.str.contains('dep')` should be faster on bigger data sets...

Comment: @MaxU, thank you so much ! I have another question, What about if I want to add another condition to extract a set of data from the cdv file. From the last column, I also want to extract rows having "30". I tried this code:   'patients[patients.dis.str.contains('dep') & patients.rank == '30' ]', but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
In [213]: patients
Out[213]:
   ID           dis  rank
0   1  dep, anxiety    30
1   2           dep    40
2   4        stress    30
3   7    dep, fobia    20

In [214]: patients[(patients['dis'].str.contains('dep')) & (patients['rank'] == 30)]
Out[214]:
   ID           dis  rank
0   1  dep, anxiety    30
```

PS `rank` is a pandas method, so you can't use dot-column (`df.column_name`) accessor, because pandas will think you are calling the `NDFrame.rank` method:

Demo:

Here we call a reference to the `NDFrame.rank` method:

```
In [215]: patients.rank
Out[215]:
<bound method NDFrame.rank of    ID           dis  rank
0   1  dep, anxiety    30
1   2           dep    40
2   4        stress    30
3   7    dep, fobia    20>
```

Here we call `rank` column:

```
In [216]: patients['rank']
Out[216]:
0    30
1    40
2    30
3    20
Name: rank, dtype: int64
```