# update csv column value

Tags: csv, python-3.5

I have a CSV file named samplecsv that has 4 fields A,B,C,D as follows:

[a1,b1,c1,2]

[a2,b2,c2,2]

[a3,b3,c3,2]

I need to update field D from '2' to '9' for all row.How can I do it. 
I try the code as follows,but did not work.

```
import csv
f = open('C:/samplecsv.csv', 'w')
writer.writerow({'D':'9'})
f.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question is unclear, Please read 
[**How to Ask a good question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and find out how to use this site
[**taking the tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @Vickel ,OK ! I try it later .Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use pandas  instead of csv

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:/samplecsv.csv")
df["D"].replace(2,9, inplace=True)
df.to_csv("C:/samplecsv.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: When I write back to CSV file ,It will add a  column having sequence value 0,1,2,3,4.... ;So the CSV file will be [0,a1,b1,c1,9],[1,a2,b2,c2,9],[2,a3,b3,c3,9]. How can I avoid the sequence value when  writing to CSV file? 3Q~

Comment: I got the answer from another question on Stack Overflow .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923281/pandas-writing-dataframe-to-csv-file