# how to write csv file using python

Tags: python, list, csv, readline

i have a python script that read from csv file and store the values in a list,
where the values are Dates row[0], float row[10] , Boolean row[11].

the script work perfectly in reading part  but when i try to write the selected values to a second CSV file the system create a file with **just the headers**, and the system crash  with displaying this error:

> line 62, in 
>   fwriter.writerow("{}:{}:{}".format(row[0],row[10],row[11]))
>
> builtins.IndexError: string index out of range

where is the error in the code?

## code:

```
          import csv

            mydelimeter = csv.excel()
            mydelimeter.delimiter=";"
            myfile = open("C:/Users/test/Documents/R_projects/homework/rdu-weather-history.csv")

            # read the first line in the opened file ==> Header
            myfile.readline()

            myreader=csv.reader(myfile,mydelimeter)

            result=[]

            '''
            create a variable that handle values of the 3 fields
 ==> Date - fastest5secwindspeed - fog
             and display the result where  
                 fog ==> Yes    and highest speed  more than 10.
            '''

            for index ,row in enumerate(myreader):
                try:
                    '''
                    check if the values in the fog colums is == Yes 
                    if ok 
                    check if the column of the "fastwindspeed" 
is  empty ==>  raise Exception
                    check if the value in column of the "fastwindspeed"
 is < 10.0 ==>  raise Exception

                    else  print the results
                    '''
                    if row[11] =="Yes":
                        if row[10] in (None, ""):
                            raise Exception( "this Record has empty value" )
                        if float(row[10]) < 10.0:
                            raise Exception( 'the wind speed  is below 10 mph in ' + row[0] )            
                        print(row[0],row[10],row[11])
                        '''
                        append the result into a list
 in order to use it in the writing of the new csv file  
                        '''
                        result.append(row[0])
                        result.append(row[10])
                        result.append(row[11])
                except Exception as e:
                    print("{}:{}".format(index ,e))
          myfile.close()
             '''
    create a second csv file and append the selected result from the  1st csv file 
    '''  
            with open("C:/Users/test/Documents/Python_Projects/rduSpeedFog.csv", "w") as f:
                headers = ["Date","WindSpeed","Fog"]

                fwriter=csv.writer(f,mydelimeter)

                fwriter.writerow(headers)

                for row in result:


                    fwriter.writerow("{}:{}:{}".format(row[0],row[10],row[11]))

                print("Writing Complete")
            f.close()
```

after using the answer of @Bamar

i got this result

[csv file as result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IYcX.png)

Comment: `result` is a list of strings, not a list of rows. The loop `for row in result:` makes no sense.

Comment: Why don't you just do that inside the `for index, row in enumerate(myreader):` loop?

Comment: @Barmar so  the loop must be on what ??

Comment: Why not make use of pandas `to_csv` ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16923367/6242649

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first loop, each string is put into a separate element of the `result` list, so it's not a list of rows.

You should change that loop to use:

```
result.append([row[0], row[10], row[11]])
```

to append those fields as a list for each row.

In the second loop you're using a `csv.writer`, so it will add the delimiters, and you shouldn't use `format`. Just write:

```
fwriter.writerow(row)
```

And if you want the field delimiter to be `:` in the output file, use:

```
fwriter=csv.writer(f,":")
```

Comment: @Bamar **first** i tried your answer it write the values but not in good format  i will edit my question and add image for the result of csv file 
**second** what  is the meaning of *

Comment: See https://codeyarns.com/2012/04/26/unpack-operator-in-python/ for what `*` means in a function argument.

Comment: You need to use a different delimiter than `mydelimiter` for the output file.

Comment: @Bamar no it seems it worked once i delete the **.format**  but i did not understand why with format did not worked as it should although i specified the **right delemiter**

Comment: The argument to `writerow` should be a list of the fields. When you formatted it, there's no list.

Comment: can i write the exception also into the new csv file ??

Comment: The first loop will have to append those to the `result` array, and then the second loop will need an `if` statement so it can process those rows differently.

Comment: when you said append those to result ? you add the **raised exceptions** to the result list ?

Comment: I meant appending the strings, like `result.append("{}:{}".format(index ,e))`

Answer (score 0):

`writerow` takes a sequence as a parameter, but you are passing a string. Try to pass your values as a list.