# How to write a dataframe and some data to an excel file in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a requirement to write data in a dataframe and three other values that i should write to an excel file.I will give the example here.
I have a dataframe  and three other values.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfDrF.jpg)

I should write data in the above format to excel file.

Comment: I guess `openpyxl` library may help you. https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ please read this manual and add some code to this question that demonstrates your effort

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple.Create a DataFrame as usual and i would append the last three rows with information in first column and empty spaces in the last. Then i would write my file to excel using *to_csv*. You can read more about it here: [Writing DataFrame to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923281/pandas-writing-dataframe-to-csv-file).

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd

my_data={'A':["2017/01/14","2017/01/02"],'M':['C','C'],'P':[8,7],'G':[1.44,1.26],'R':[0.8,0.7],'N':[2,8]}

df=pd.DataFrame(my_data)

#Add the extra rows
df.loc[-1]=['Total M: ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
df.index=df.index+1
df.loc[-1]=['Total G: ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
df.index=df.index+1
df.loc[-1]=['Total R: ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']

#Write to excel
df.to_csv('FileName',sep='\t',encoding='utf-8',index=False)
```

From next time, it would be appreciated if you post what you have tried.
Good Luck!
May the *CODE* be with you!

Comment: Hi @Me-So-Cool, thanks for the reply , the above code didn't worked for me,
 `df = pd.DataFrame(mr)
 df = df.append(pd.Series(t_s_amount, index=df.columns[:len(t_s_amount)]),ignore_index=True)
    df = df.append(pd.Series(t_gst_amount, index=df.columns[:len(t_s_amount)]), ignore_index=True)
    df = df.append(pd.Series(t_r_amount, index=df.columns[:len(t_s_amount)]), ignore_index=True)
    df.to_excel(new_file_name,index=False)`
this piece of code is doing the job.....

Comment: again Hi @Me-So-Cool,but the problem is while i am writing my data to excel, Date is getting changed from **yyyymmdd** to **yyyymmdd hh mm ss**
Previouly i worked with XLSXWRITER there i had an option to fomat, but here I am not able to do . Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why isn't the above code working? Can you specify the error? It works fine for me!

Comment: Hi @Me-So-Cool, ** ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns**
I am getting the above error, but the which i have commented is working for me, and i have tried your code this way,

`df = pd.DataFrame(mr)

    # Add the extra rows
    df.loc[-1] =t_s_amount
    df.index = df.index + 1
    df.loc[-1] = t_gst_amount
    df.index = df.index + 1
    df.loc[-1] = t_r_amount

    # Write to excel
    df.to_csv(new_file_name, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', index=False) `

Comment: Yes @Me-So-Cool my modifications are working, only one problem is when i am writing **Date** information to excel the data is getting stored in **yyyymmdd hh mm ss** instead  of **yyyymmdd** . I need the latter format.

Comment: [Excel Date and time formatting](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-date-and-time-formatting) This may help you. And please upvote if the solution worked. Cheers!

Comment: hey @Me-So-Cool, my problem is not with excel, while i am writing data frame to excel using df.to_excel(filename), suppose if i have  **26-06-1990** , it getting written as ** 26-06-1990 00:00:00**

Comment: Yeah I get it. So write it in that way, and why not change the format in excel afterwards?

Comment: It can be changed after, but i don't want user to do anything , if everything is handled by us then it will be good..!!