# Why doesn't the clean-up persist?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-applymap

I clean a csv table. I want to delete symbols in the ID. It looks like this:

```
ID    Address
"(2   Hamburg
"(3   Cologne
"(4   Berlin
"(5   ...
```

I want to delete the `"(`

The code I used

`Ost.applymap(lambda x: x.replace('"(', ''))`

when I check the csv file after saving, the deleted symbols are back. Like nothing changed. Why is the change not saving?

Comment: Can you provide the code where you save your `Ost` as that sounds like the culprit of your issue.

Adittionaly, can you verify that `Ost` is modified after doing `applymap`?

Comment: yes, `Ost` shows me as modified after `applymap` . I thought the write mode saves it? `Ost.to_csv('ostarbeiter.csv')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reassign the change to the variable:

```py
Ost = Ost.applymap(lambda x: x.replace('"(', ''))
```

The output of:

```py
Ost.applymap(lambda x: x.replace('"(', ''))
Ost
```

is

```py
    ID    Address
0    (2   Hamburg
1    (3   Cologne
2    (4   Berlin
```

As you can see it isn't applymap isn't make the change inplace

Comment: No problem.  Happens to me all the time.  Get in the habit of calling the DataFrame when troubleshooting code.  On the surface it would seem something is going on with saving.  Calling the df reveals that nothing changed with the applymap.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound stupid, but have you [saved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16923367/5521670) the file after doing the `applymap`?

That might be the reason why your `csv` file is unchanged. The data changes in memory, but is never written into the "clean" `csv` file.

Comment: yes, I have saved it as csv -->  Ost.to_csv('ostarbeiter.csv')

Comment: I have saved it properly. Where can the problem be?