# How to save pandas dataframe to a .csv with specific filename?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

For example I import csv file as data frame and work on some process on pandas

```py
df = pd.read_csv('./label/101_5603_2019-05-02~2019-05-18.csv')
rest of codes to work on the data
```

How do I save the result to a new csv file with the names including 8 first character of the original csv files (101_5603.csv)? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a pandas DataFrame to CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923281/writing-a-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
import os

f = './label/101_5603_2019-05-02~2019-05-18.csv'
url, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))
new = url[:8] + ext
print (new)
101_5603.csv

new = os.path.dirname(f) + '/' + url[:8] + ext
print (new)
./label/101_5603.csv

new = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(f), url[:8] + ext)
print (new)
./label\101_5603.csv
```

And pass it to [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df.to_csv(new, index=False)
```