# How to take input from the user and store it in an external file?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a quiz which is supposed to have a registration feature that stores the user input into an external file. I just need help on how to store the user input.

This is my code:

```
def register():
    name = input("Please enter your full name: ")
    age = input("Please enter your age: ")
    year = input("Please enter your year group: ")
    username = (name[:3] + age)
    print("Your username is " + username)
    password = input("Please enter a password: ")
```

Comment: An online tutorial like this [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp) could help

Comment: It helped a bit but I'm still very confused.

Comment: What are you confused about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programming can be confusing, all you need is to be organized.

Here is an algorithm for you.

1. Create a file
2. Write data to the file
3. Close the file

And the code:

```
#Create a new function
def register():
    #Open a file to store the input
    with open("credentials.txt", 'a') as out:
        #Ask for the data
        name = input("Please enter your full name: ")
        age = input("Please enter your age: ")
        year = input("Please enter your year group: ")
        username = (name[:3] + age)
        print("Your username is " + username)
        #Save to the file
        out.write(username + "\n")
        password = input("Please enter a password: ")
        out.write(password  + "\n")
        print("Login created!")
        #Close the file
        out.close()    

#Entry point of your program
register()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot. I also need to create a log in feature. I've already asked the user for input but I need it to look for their details in the text file and if it's there, they will be logged in and be moved on to the quiz. I just need help on this then I think I'll ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write those variables to the file like this :

`filehandle = open("filename", "a")
filehandle.write(name + "\t" + age + "\t" + age + "\t" + year +"\t" + password + "\t")
filehandle.close()`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this and I'll mention them all below:

- You can save information of all the user by using pickle where it creates a dictionary and each user can be a key and it's information as a list of values. You can also load that information back later on. Here's a link to understand more how pickle works. Check out the answers of various user: [How can I use pickle to save a dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218477/how-can-i-use-pickle-to-save-a-dict?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- Another way is to save it in a text file as mentioned by [sirandy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670134/sirandy).
- Third way is to create a pandas dataframe and save information of each user as a new row. I am assuming you are aware of pandas dataframes. Here's a link again to explain how to do this: [Writing a pandas DataFrame to CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923281/writing-a-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-file)