# beautiful soup web scrape

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
print(soup.title)
print(soup.title.string)

r = requests.get 
('https://www.
street/
print(len(r.text))
```

now i need to extract data.

I've tries something like this

```
results = soup.find_all('tr')
r = []
for count in range(0, 6): 
    k = k.next_sibling
    r.append(k.string)
    results.append(r)
print('Number of results', len(results))
    for row in range(0, len(results)):
print(results[row])
```

but this doesnt return me anything. how can I extract the data from the web ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get all `div` with class `tr` with `soup.findAll("div", {"class":"tr"})`. This would return all div container with that class.

Note that those div have also the data in html attributes such as `data-unit`, `data-size`, `data-price`... so it makes things easier for scraping those values

Code :

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.cityrealty.com/nyc/roosevelt-island/rivercross-531-main-street/closing-history/57182')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
data = [
    t.attrs
    for t in soup.findAll("div", {"class":"tr"})
    if t.has_attr("data-unit")
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
del df['class']
print(df)
```

Output :

```
   data-unit data-size data-sizeft data-price data-priceft data-priceask   data-date data-total
0       1916         3        1777    1175000          661       1250000  1587700800         84
1       1612         2        1364    1150000          843       1250000  1580274000         84
2        411         1         972     620000          638        640000  1580101200         84
3       1003         3        1777    1131000          636       1245000  1577077200         84
4       1411         1           -     682000            -             -  1576731600         84
..       ...       ...         ...        ...          ...           ...         ...        ...
79      1403                     -      52877            -             -  1138683600         84
80      1315                     -      54921            -             -  1135141200         84
81       123                     -      52241            -             -  1093406400         84
82      1915                     -      51037            -             -  1058932800         84
83      1819                     -      53642            -             -  1049688000         84

[84 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: thank you so much !  also how can I save it as csv file ?  I've tried this following :       
import csv
with open('cityrealty.csv','w') as f:
    w=csv.writer(f)
    w.writerows(data.items())     //but this gives me an attribute error

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-d95e7648ef0e> in <module>
      3 with open('cityrealty.csv','w') as f:
      4     w=csv.writer(f)
----> 5     w.writerows(data.items())

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: you can save the pandas dataframe to csv https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923281/writing-a-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-file