# writing arrays to csv file in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I m triying to write
np.array(covid_df['datetime'])  and np.array(covid_df['value'])

to csv file with heading  in python3
"date" and "value"

how can I do that?

Comment: Is `covid_df` a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing a pandas DataFrame to CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923281/writing-a-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-file)

Answer (score 0):

arr = np.array(covid_df['datetime'])

np.savetxt('array.csv', [arr], delimiter=',', fmt='%d')

I can do this only "datetime" but I want to write with "value" and headers