# How to convert a pandas dataframe saved as file with no file type to csv or txt format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and programming in general. I am running a simulator which generates output files of simulation as log files which are pandas dataframes.

However, I need to read through these dataframes.

I am running the simulator in the command terminal and the file path for the logs generated is like this:

C:\Users\HitBuy Atrium\Downloads\abides-master\abides-master\log\rmsc03_two_hour

These are stored as zip files, extracting which yields files with no file types.

My question - how to read these pandas dataframes generated which are stored as zip files using python in the command terminal.

In other IDEs I know it is done using

`Dataframe.to_csv`

But, for this case, I am running into trouble where a lsit of dataframes are generated as zip files and I need to read them.

Comment: look the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923281/writing-a-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-file)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. The links mention for dataframes already in the runtime programe. But, the dataframes here are stored in a separate location as I have mentioned in the question. How to call them and convert them is my query.