# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 202-203: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to write a data stored in a dataframe to a csv and am running into the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 202-203: character maps to <undefined>
```

I looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923281/writing-a-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-file) and tried their solutions of adding `encoding='utf-8'`  however this did not seem to help. I was wondering if there is another encoding recommendation/ alternative solution to this problem. The code for my function that writes to the csv is as follows:

```
def data_to_csv(data, data2):
    encode = 'utf-8'
    with open('data.csv', 'w') as data_csv:
        data.to_csv(path_or_buf=data_csv, encoding=encode)
    with open('data2_data.csv', 'w') as data2_csv:
        data2.to_csv(path_or_buf=data2_csv, encoding=encode)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So, what does your data look like? Esp. at position 202-203?

Comment: I will see if I can figure that out @M.Spiller either way i would assume utf-8 should allow it to work because they are all keys you would find on an english keyboard

Comment: @M.Spiller it appears to be an emoji. I can see how this may cause issues. Any idea regarding how to deal with that issue? Also, is it even switching encoding to utf-8 based on the error?

Comment: I would try to write to a UTF-8 file. I.e. pass `encoding='utf-8'` to the call to `open` (not (only) to `to_csv`)

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you @M.Spiller !! If you want to put this as the solution to the problem I would be happy to mark it as the correct solution!

Comment: Sure. Added as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error message, the content of `data` does contain some characters that cannot be encoded as `charmap`.

You try to write the data encoded as UTF-8, but in order to do so, you should open/create your .csv files with UTF-8 encoding:

```py
with open('data.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as data_csv:
```

should work.