# How to Write csv or any file in local system using Pyspark?

Tags: csv, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, hive, jupyter

below is the syntax

```
new_df.write.format("csv").mode('overwrite').save("C:/Users/DELL/Downloads/Spark_Tut/tut.csv")
```

> [Error File 1 : Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o59.csv.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHUPj.png)

*I want to Save data in csv or any file system in my Local machine.*

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing a pandas DataFrame to CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923281/writing-a-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-file)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.